RDP doesn't keep sessions alive in Ubuntu 24.04 after disconnecting
So I am using RDP with Ubuntu 24.04. However, whenever I disconnect or close the session, all the apps that I had open terminate.
Next rdp starts with a clean environment.
Is there a way I can keep the sessions saved like in Windows 11 where even if I disconnect the session, all the apps are still in the same state when I reconnect using RDP ?

Are you using xrdp with Ubuntu or the built in remote login? Or the built in remote desktop sharing?

You may find this answer useful.

That's not what I have observed. After reading your question, and while I was just starting to type this comment, I hit the x on the RDP session. When I reconnected, I finished making this comment. I too use a windows client with RDP to access the Ubuntu 24.04 system. I do not attempt to access the primary ID which is always 'logged on' at the Ubuntu system console. I created a different ID for my Ubuntu needs, including the firefox I am now using to make this response.
My windows clients are XP
My installation notes to get remote desktop on XUbuntu include:

Install xrdp
Be sure the firewall allows it to use port 3389
Prior to XUbuntu 22.04, it was necessary to modify /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini to insure it included KillDisconnected=1, which is no longer necessary as of 22.04
Changes to /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini include

change crypt_level to none
change ssl_protcols from TLSV1.2, TLSv1.3 to be
TLSv1, TSLv1.1, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3
allow_channels was TRUE, make it FALSE




I use the standard mstsc.exe, which comes with the Windows operating system.  Some may think of it as "Remote Desktop Connection" under Accessories at the Start menu.  I think I've also tried it on a Windows 10 machine as well.

I'll add my notes to my answer
